# How do I gift a tuning in Forza 4?

Tags: forza-motorsport-4

How do I gift a tuning in Forza 4? Also, how do I unlock the tunings I create so I may share them with my club members?

Answer (score 1):

You can only gift `unlocked` tunes to someone else, i.e. tunes that you made or were gifted, but not the ones you buy at a storefront.

Having said that, you can gift your tuning setup by going to `Upgrades` > `My tuning setups` and find the setup there. Press `A` for a menu and select `Gift`. You can then select the friend from the list to gift it to. They have to be on your friends list!

When you gift a tuning setup to someone, it's always unlocked. Only when someone buys or downloads a tuning setup from your storefront, it is locked, even if you offer it for free.